# how to keep count on how many left of the instantiated clones i.e enemy

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using the following script to instantiate the enemy clones but I'm unable to keep track of how many have been instantiated or are left in the scene.

```
public GameObject playerhealth;
public GameObject enemy;
public float spawnTime= 3f;
public Transform spawnPoint;

public float dis;
public static GameObject obj;

void Start(){
    Invoke ("Spawn", spawnTime);
}

void Spawn(){

    if (dis < 100) {

        obj =   Instantiate (enemy, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);

        obj.name = "Abc";

    }
}
```

Comment: why not add them to a collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of your enemies by adding/removing them from a `List` as you spawn and destroy them.

```
List<GameObject> enemies = new List<GameObject>();

obj = Instantiate (enemy, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);
enemies.Add(obj);
```

When you need to remove it, simply call `enemies.Remove()` and pass a reference to the enemy GameObject being removed.

You can also use `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` to find all enemies in your scene after the fact if they all have the same tag.

```
GameObject[] enemies;

enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
```

Answer (score 2):

I would sugest you to use a component attached, so you can use it for all prefabs, and adapt it in every project, to retrieve your counter just use `EnemyCounter.enemiesAlive`. You have to attach this script to your enemy prefab/s and it will work if you want just the counter. if you also want to keep track of your enemy prefabs use a List<> as suggested in other answers.

```
public class EnemyCounter: MonoBehaviour
  {
    public static int enemiesAlive=0;

    void OnEnable()
      {
        enemiesAlive++;
      }

    void OnDisable()
      {
        enemiesAlive--;
      }

}
```

Comment: Screaming `ScriptableObject`

Comment: Can't agree more, but if the guy is asking such a question i think he has to handle MonoBehaviour first

Comment: If it's a script used as an add-on to the enemy prefab `OnEnable()` is going to be called as soon as the Enemy is instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

```
    List <GameObject> _list; 
public GameObject obj;

 void Spawn()
{

if (dis < 100) {

    obj =   Instantiate (enemy, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);

    obj.name = "Abc";
    _list.Add(obj);

}

   void Update()

{
 //TO get count
  _list.Count;
 }
```